# Ansible - Windows path variable

Tags: windows, path, ansible

Is there away to use variables and string together? For example I would like to, define my path's and other options combining variables and string?

```
#Add Directory
- name: Add Directory
win_file: 
      path: "{{directory_path}}\AppName-{{env}}"
      state: directory

#Add IUSR to directory path
- name: ADD IUSR
win_acl:
      path: "{{directory_path}}\AppName-{{env}}"
      user: IUSR
      rights: Read
      type: allow
      state: present
      propagation: 'NoPropagateInherit'

#Add website
- name: "{{env}} Add App Name"
win_iis_website:
      name: "AppName-{{env}}"
      state: started
      port: 80
      ip: "{{serverip}}"
      hostname: "appname-{{env}}.com"
      application_pool: "{{application_pool4}}"
      physical_path: "{{directory_path}}\AppName-{{env}}"
register: website
```

Sure there is a simple answer but can't find one at the minute

Comment: You have to quote Windows path delimiters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declarations of *path*  shall be single-quoted ('). Then the backslash (\) won't be interpreted as an escape character. See [Gotchas](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas)

> The difference between single quotes and double quotes is that in double quotes you can use escapes

```
path: '{{ directory_path }}\AppName-{{ env }}'
```

The indentation of the code is wrong. The correct syntax is below

```
tasks:
    #Add Directory
  - name: Add Directory
    win_file:
      path: '{{ directory_path }}\AppName-{{ env }}'
      state: directory
    #Add IUSR to directory path
  - name: ADD IUSR
    win_acl:
      path: '{{ directory_path }}\AppName-{{ env }}'
      user: IUSR
      rights: Read
      type: allow
      state: present
      propagation: 'NoPropagateInherit'
    #Add website
  - name: "{{ env }} Add App Name"
    win_iis_website:
      name: "AppName-{{ env }}"
      state: started
      port: 80
      ip: "{{ serverip }}"
      hostname: "appname-{{ env }}.com"
      application_pool: "{{ application_pool4 }}"
      physical_path: '{{ directory_path }}\AppName-{{ env }}'
    register: website
```

It's a good idea to test the playbooks with *ansible-lint*.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir that was my problem, how reviewed made those changes and all seems fine now. Just had a look at ansible-lint - will look into incorporating that