# How to join Path in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to make or join path in Ansible. When I was running below code then I am getting an error.

Code:

```yaml
---
- name: Project1
  hosts: target_hosts

  vars:
    Data: '{{get_data}}' #input from user
    src_inst: '{{get_inst}}' #input from user 

  tasks:
  - name: set path 
    set_fact:
      main_path : '{{ ("\\abc.de.net\xyz\\mn\", src_inst, "\temp") | path_join }}'
    when: Data == 'qaz'
```

Error:

> Unexcepted failure during module execution.

If user give input Data = 'qaz' and src_inst = 'w_123'

```
Desired Output:
main_path = "\\abc.de.net\xyz\\mn\w_123\temp"
```

Do you know how to solve this error or how to join path?

Comment: Thanks. Just corrected. It would be very great if you can help.

Comment: You'll need to give more input like what is the value of `get_inst`, where is it defined/assigned, same for `get_data`. What would be usefull to is that you provide the  **full** error message, and not a reduced version of it, if you want us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. get_inst is a string User will input that. But it is a string. About error, its almost full error but sorry for could not paste as I am posting this from my personal laptop.

Comment: The backslashes don't make sense to me. Can you post your input and desired output?

Comment: @vee If user give input Data = 'qaz' and src_inst = 'w_123'

Desired Output:
main_path = "\\abc.de.net\xyz\\mn\w_123\temp"

Comment: Try this @Herry: ```tasks:
- name: set path 
  set_fact:
    main_path: "{{ '\'.join(('\\abc.de.net\xyz\\mn', src_inst, 'temp')) }}"
  when: Data == 'qaz' and src_inst == 'w_123'```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible - Windows path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022727/ansible-windows-path-variable)

Comment: Thank you. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, path_join cannot be used for Windows paths, use string concatenation instead, the module error was most probably because you were escaping a " so quotes were imbalanced.

Try something like this instead:

```
---
- name: Project1
  hosts: target_hosts

  vars:
    Data: '{{get_data}}' #input from user
    src_inst: '{{get_inst}}' #input from user 

  tasks:
  - name: set path 
    set_fact:
      main_path : '\\abc.de.net\xyz\\mn\{{ src_inst }}\temp'
    when: Data == 'qaz'
```

Comment: `path_join` will use `/` as a path separator regardless of the platform. That might be fine though: i.e. `win_find` works fine with a path that mixes ``\`` and `/`.